# Is it possible to prove this function is computationally intistinguishable from PRF？

Tags: pseudo-random-function, indistinguishability

**Background**

I have constructed a function $F':X × K → Y$, which has a characteristic that the quantity of $x\in X$ mapping to a single $y\in Y$ follows a binomial distribution $B(\frac{1}{2}, 2\frac{|X|}{|Y|})$.While a pseudorandom function $F: X × K → Y$, where the quantity of $x\in X$ mapping to a single $y\in Y$ follows a binomial distribution $B(\frac{1}{|Y|}, |X|)$.Formally speaking,define $Y_k'^y=\{x|F'_k(x)=y,x\in X \} ,y \in Y,|Y'^y_k|\sim B(\frac{1}{2}, 2\frac{|X|}{|Y|})$,and $Y_k^y=\{ x|F_k(x)=y,x\in X\} ,y \in Y,|Y_k^y|\sim B(\frac{1}{|Y|}, |X|)$.

**Question**

It is evident that $F'$ and $F$ are not statistically indistinguishable, but can we prove that they are computationally indistinguishable? If they are not computationally indistinguishable, does it imply that $F'$ is insecure?

Comment: Are you saying that it is computationally hard to show that $F'$ follows a different distribution? Because if that's not the case then it is not computationally secure.

Comment: Yes,that's exactly what I mean.I wonder if there is some methods to show that $F'$ is computationally indistinguishable from $F$.If not, which type of security does it satisfies?This is an interesting question for it's defined by the distribution of the map between input and output,and I've never seen a method to prove such a function computationally secure.

Comment: I feel this is a bit of a reversal of sorts. If something can be *statistically or otherwise* be shown to be distinguishable *then it is not secure*. Now you are saying that it is statistically distinguishable (if we get rid of the double negation) but not computationally distinguishable. To me that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That may not be true.DDH question is a computationally secure question while it's not a statically secure question.